# Не печатается значение, которое возвращает геттер

Tags: java, getter

Хочу вывести в консоль значение, которое мне возвращает геттер, но он не выводится! Объясните пожалуйста, в чем дело?

```java
import java.util.Date;

public abstract class Fish {

    private int price;
    private Date shelfLife;

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public void setShelfLife(Date shelfLife) {
        this.shelfLife = shelfLife;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public Date getFish() {
        return shelfLife;
    }

}
```

```java
public class Salmon extends Fish {

    Salmon(){
        getPrice();
    }

    @Override
    public int getPrice() {
        return 100;
    }
}
```

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Salmon salmon = new Salmon();
    }
}
```

На сколько мне известно, если пометить в конструктор значение, и в классе Майн создать экземпляр класса, где создан конструктор, выведется все, что есть в конструкторе, так почему же поля выводятся, а методы нет?

Comment: и при создании экземпляра класса, и последующем вызове метода через него у меня так же ничего не выводится!

Comment: Вы ничего не выводите. Чтобы что-то вывести надо так написать: `System.out.println(ТУТ ЧТО-ТО)`. Например `System.out.println(getPrice())`

Comment: Но почему же указав в том же конструкторе String a = "FISH", он выводится и без sout?

Comment: Он не должен просто так выводится. Если выводится - значит вы не всё рассказали про ваш код в вопросе.

Comment: Возможно я запутался... спасибо, уже понятно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Понял в чем дело! 
Забыл поместить getPrice() в System.out.println();